# Report link to other report (SSRS)

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

Hi I have a report and I am trying to add a text box in which it will be a link to another report when clicked. The linked report has a multi-valued parameter which is a list of databases.

I am wondering what I need to put in the "Value" box from this [picture.](http://s4.postimg.org/5ye31r9zh/link.png).

I have tried 
`&parameterName=”+JOIN(Parameters!parameterName.Value,"&parameterName=") +”`

and other variations of that expression with no luck. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't access your picture link, but if you are setting the value of a multivalued parameter in your subreport then you dont need the &parameterName just =JOIN(Parameters!parameterName.Value,",") will do.

Comment: That makes sense. I already had the parameters set so makes sense now... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can't access your picture link, but if you are setting the value of a multivalued parameter in your subreport then you dont need the &parameterName just

```
=Parameters!parameterName.Value
```

will do.

Comment: If I have a function that is already handling the comma separated list, do i need that ","???

Comment: Is the parameterName in the parent report multivlaued as well?

Comment: Actually after seeing your screenshot the above would do. No need of Join.